# Persisting Entities with multi-part foreign keys in Hibernate 6

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate 6.2.22, unfortunately newer versions are not possible at the moment for most likely unrelated reasons.

I have created the entities User, Organization, and UserOrganization, as n users can be part of m organizations. I have shortened the classes to show them here, basically, there are attributes tied to either of both entities and attributes tied to the relation.  I have not added @ManyToMany because I never need to access the relation without also accessing some of the attributes tied to it.

Shortening was needed both to make it readable and appease the stakeholder, please feel free to request updates in case I have messed up something important in the process.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @MapKey(name = "organization")
    private Map<Organization,UserOrganization> userOrganizations = new HashMap<Organization,UserOrganization>();    
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @MapKey(name = "user")
    private Map<User,UserOrganization> userOrganizations = new HashMap<User,UserOrganization>();
}

@Entity
public class UserOrganization {
    @EmbeddedId 
    private UserOrganizationId id;
    
    @MapsId("organizationsId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organizationsId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_users_organizations_organizations_id"))
    private Organization organization;

    @MapsId("usersId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)   
    @JoinColumn(name = "usersId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_users_organizations_users_id"))
    private User user;
    protected UserOrganization() {}  

    @Column(name="usersId", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Long usersId;
    
    @Column(name="organizationsId", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Long organizationsId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean contactPerson;
}

@Embeddable
public class UserOrganizationId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "usersId")
    private Long usersId;

    @Column(name = "organizationsId")
    private Long organizationsId;

    public Long getUsersId() {
        return usersId;
    }

    public void setUsersId(Long usersId) {
        this.usersId = usersId;
    }

    public Long getOrganizationsId() {
        return organizationsId;
    }

    public void setOrganizationsId(Long organizationsId) {
        this.organizationsId = organizationsId;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof UserOrganizationId)) {
            return false;
        }
        UserOrganizationId otherUserOrganizationId = (UserOrganizationId)other;
        return Objects.equals(usersId, otherUserOrganizationId.usersId) &&
                Objects.equals(organizationsId, otherUserOrganizationId.organizationsId);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(usersId, organizationsId);
    }
}
```

The relation table has a multi-part PK. So far it works. Dump from PostgreSQL 11 DB looks fine.

Now a user can post an announcement related to one of their organizations. Thus, there is the announcement entity.

```
@Entity
public class Announcement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR")
    private String message;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR")
    private String title;

    @MapsId("id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)   
    @JoinColumns({  // foreign key name does not seem to work for multi-part keys
        @JoinColumn(name = "organizations_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_announcements_users_organizations_organizations_id"), nullable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "users_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_announcements_users_organizations_users_id"), nullable=false)
    })
    private UserOrganization userOrganization;
}
```

In the DB, it still works, as long as I enter the announcements from external SQL test code.

Once I create an announcement from Java using JPA/Hibernate, I can persist it. A row in the DB is added. However, the multi-part FK is null. The connecting to the UserOrganization is lost. Thus, I made it non-nullable. Since then, I cannot persist it anymore, Hibernate creates SQL code that tries to set null values.

If I check the Announcement object in Eclipse before persisting, it has a UserOrganization set. The UserOrganization has a valid PK-pair set. The EntityManager contains the instance of the UserOrganization entity. What is wrong?